# Merging a picture in to background similar to the picture in the link below

Tags: adobe, photoshop, image-editing, photoshop-cs4

I am trying to merge two pictures to make it appear like the 1st image in this [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IQZY7.jpg). I want to merge the 2nd pic in to the 3rd pic and it should be merged similar to the 1st pic. How do I do that? Is there any specific name for this type of editing, so that I can search for some tutorials. Thanks in advance!

Comment: did the answers given solve your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to the "teeth whitening" image right?
Create 2 different layers for the 2 images, use the [layer mask](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/basics/layers/layer-masks/) tool on your second layer, located on the bottom of the layers panel. Once you have created a layer mask, Use the gradient tool on the mask to fade the second layer and allow the first to show through.